# How do I show image after using file upload before POST but after upload in PHP

Tags: php, upload

How do I show an image after uploading instead of displaying just the image name? This should happen before I post the form but after I upload the image file.

Comment: If you are uploading the image file, you would HAVE to post the form - it's the only way to upload. Typically what sites do is that they have the upload in an IFRAME and when a users selects an image, that iframe posts to upload, and on the refresh, it shows the image. You would have to do some extra work to keep track of the image being uploaded, so when you post your main form, you know which image to associate with the data

Comment: This seems a bit more complex than what I have initially anticipated..maybe I'll just skip this step. Thanks!

Comment: How do you upload an image without actually posting the form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some form of ajax image uploading (searching google produces many results for that). When your ajax uploading script returns a response of a filename, just insert the filename inside the  tag and append it inside your form.